# Having trouble with SPI in Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, accelerometer, spi

I have a project where I am trying to use the `adxl345` as a pedometer and it is hooked up to an `Arduino` where it will count steps.I also have a bluetooth device from `Adafruit (nrf8001)` that is hooked up to an `Arduino`.

I want to the Arduino to send the steps via bluetooth to an smart phone. **The problem** I am currently at is the Arduino can only use either the adxl345 or the nrf8001. I cannot have both using SPI communication. I know that SPI can have multiple devices attached to it using chip select. I am using slave select but I don't know why it is not working. According to Adafruit they use their own special SPI communication that not only uses chip select but also a reset and interrupt.

Comment: Hi Seng, You must make your question easily understandable by formatting it better. Read the site's help, thanks.

Comment: Are you have problems with SPI when only one device is placed to the board? Try to minimize task and divide it to steps, for example:
1) implement low level code part realted to first device
2) ... to second device
3) implement high level code

Comment: Individually they work perfectly fine. However, when I try to get them to work at the same time, they conflict with one another.

Comment: @RubenMasso: Ever solve this problem of SPI conflict between NRF8001 and another slave?

Answer (score 0):

Read following page.

https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/pinouts

It's `REQ` pin is considered as chip select.

Comment: I know that. I gave both the accelerometer and the nrf8001 there own pin for chip select on the Arduino. But, I cannot get them to work with each other.